# asp.net webrequest handle

Tags: asp.net

Hi 
I am using webclient request and it returns me whole html page in my c# code now i want to get some part of the page so please help me to do this.

Thanks

Munish

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to download, parse and query the webpage.

```
HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load(txtLink.Text);
```

From the site:

> This is an agile HTML parser that builds a read/write DOM and supports plain XPATH or XSLT (you actually don't HAVE to understand XPATH nor XSLT to use it, don't worry...). It is a .NET code library that allows you to parse "out of the web" HTML files. The parser is very tolerant with "real world" malformed HTML. The object model is very similar to what proposes System.Xml, but for HTML documents (or streams).